# Is this algorithm O(1)?

Tags: complexity-theory

Is the following algorithm simply O(1), or is its complexity trickier to define?

```
for (i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    if (i > 10)
        break;
```

I'm confused by the fact that it's obviously O(n) when n <= 10.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asymptote. It is O(1) because it is a time-constant operation.

Comment: As the for loop terminates when `i > 10`, it only loops a constant number of time (i.e. independent of `n`), the running time is `O(1)`

Comment: The loop is deceiving because generally this kind of loop would mean O(n).  However, the `if` statement insures a constraint.  It will never past 10.  10 is a constant therefor it's O(1).  Good question by the way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's O(1) because it takes constant time regardless of the size of the input (n). Saying it's O(n) when n <= 10 does not make sense because the big-oh notation is defined in terms of asymptotic function growth, i.e., for n "large", or bigger than a certain value. This is because the actual value of n does not matter to the asymptotic complexity: it's a way to compare different algorithms to each other.

Just take a look at the [definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation) of big-oh: a function f(n) is O(g(n)) if there exists a constant c>0 and a positive integer m so that f(n)<c*g(n) for n>m. In your case f(n) is the time it takes to run your algorithm, g(n)=1, m=10 and c is proportional to the time it takes to loop through 10 integers.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's O(1). It is equivalent to say that a function is O(1) and to say it is bounded. The running time of that code is bounded, therefore it is O(1).